# IoT Mysql Query sometimes i got - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, sql, iot

I have te next Query:

```
SELECT IF(IF(atmp = 1 AND h_start1 <= (SELECT HOUR(NOW())) AND
             (SELECT HOUR(NOW())) <= h_stop1 OR
             h_start2 <= (SELECT HOUR(NOW())) AND
             (SELECT HOUR(NOW())) <= h_stop2,
             t_temp1,
             set_temp) < temp - modEn AND ccl = 1,
          1,
          0) clima,
       IF(IF(atmp = 1 AND h_start1 <= (SELECT HOUR(NOW())) AND
             (SELECT HOUR(NOW())) <= h_stop1 OR
             h_start2 <= (SELECT HOUR(NOW())) AND
             (SELECT HOUR(NOW())) <= h_stop2,
             t_temp1,
             set_temp) > temp + modEn AND cct = 1,
          1,
          0) centrala,
       'studio' camera
  FROM (SELECT (SELECT date
                  FROM termostat
                 WHERE topic = 'control-clima'
                   AND incapere = 'studio'
                   AND zi = 'miercuri') ccl,
               (SELECT date
                  FROM termostat
                 WHERE topic = 'control-centrala'
                   AND incapere = 'studio'
                   AND zi = 'miercuri') cct,
               (SELECT date
                  FROM termostat
                 WHERE topic = 'auto-temp'
                   AND incapere = 'studio'
                   AND zi = 'miercuri') atmp,
               (SELECT date
                  FROM termostat
                 WHERE topic = 'mod'
                   AND incapere = 'studio'
                   AND zi = 'miercuri') modEn,
               (SELECT date
                  FROM termostat
                 WHERE topic = 't-temp1'
                   AND incapere = 'studio'
                   AND zi = 'miercuri') t_temp1,
               (SELECT date
                  FROM termostat
                 WHERE topic = 't-temp2'
                   AND incapere = 'studio'
                   AND zi = 'miercuri') t_temp2,
               (SELECT date
                  FROM termostat
                 WHERE topic = 'h-start1'
                   AND incapere = 'studio'
                   AND zi = 'miercuri') h_start1,
               (SELECT date
                  FROM termostat
                 WHERE topic = 'h-start2'
                   AND incapere = 'studio'
                   AND zi = 'miercuri') h_start2,
               (SELECT date
                  FROM termostat
                 WHERE topic = 'h-stop1'
                   AND incapere = 'studio'
                   AND zi = 'miercuri') h_stop1,
               (SELECT date
                  FROM termostat
                 WHERE topic = 'h-stop2'
                   AND incapere = 'studio'
                   AND zi = 'miercuri') h_stop2,
               (SELECT date
                  FROM termostat
                 WHERE topic = 'set-temp'
                   AND incapere = 'studio'
                   AND zi = 'miercuri') set_temp,
               (SELECT date
                  FROM termostat
                 WHERE topic = 'studio/climat/temperatura') temp) t1
```

Everything goes good but un studio room chip, i have the problem `Subquery returns more than 1 row` 
With the same code i can read heating and a/c data on speciefied room and day from the rest of the rooms...

Maybe some of you are kind an help me on improvement of the query too (I know it is much space for better!)

Thankyou guys!

Comment: you might use aggregations within the subqueries such as `SELECT max(date) ...`

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan What actually does `max()` in my case?

Comment: It returns only one row for each subqueries.

Comment: Thankyou, is working! :)

Answer (score 0):

As @BarbarosOzhan mentioned, the solve of my problem wax `max()` function in my subqueries.
My new and working query is:

```
SELECT IF(IF(atmp = 1 AND h_start1 <= (SELECT HOUR(NOW())) AND
         (SELECT HOUR(NOW())) <= h_stop1 OR
         h_start2 <= (SELECT HOUR(NOW())) AND
         (SELECT HOUR(NOW())) <= h_stop2,
         t_temp1,
         set_temp) < temp - modEn AND ccl = 1,
      1,
      0) clima,
   IF(IF(atmp = 1 AND h_start1 <= (SELECT HOUR(NOW())) AND
         (SELECT HOUR(NOW())) <= h_stop1 OR
         h_start2 <= (SELECT HOUR(NOW())) AND
         (SELECT HOUR(NOW())) <= h_stop2,
         t_temp1,
         set_temp) > temp + modEn AND cct = 1,
      1,
      0) centrala,
   'studio' camera
FROM (SELECT (SELECT max(date)
              FROM termostat
             WHERE topic = 'control-clima'
               AND incapere = 'studio'
               AND zi = 'miercuri') ccl,
           (SELECT max(date)
              FROM termostat
             WHERE topic = 'control-centrala'
               AND incapere = 'studio'
               AND zi = 'miercuri') cct,
           (SELECT max(date)
              FROM termostat
             WHERE topic = 'auto-temp'
               AND incapere = 'studio'
               AND zi = 'miercuri') atmp,
           (SELECT max(date)
              FROM termostat
             WHERE topic = 'mod'
               AND incapere = 'studio'
               AND zi = 'miercuri') modEn,
           (SELECT max(date)
              FROM termostat
             WHERE topic = 't-temp1'
               AND incapere = 'studio'
               AND zi = 'miercuri') t_temp1,
           (SELECT max(date)
              FROM termostat
             WHERE topic = 't-temp2'
               AND incapere = 'studio'
               AND zi = 'miercuri') t_temp2,
           (SELECT max(date)
              FROM termostat
             WHERE topic = 'h-start1'
               AND incapere = 'studio'
               AND zi = 'miercuri') h_start1,
           (SELECT max(date)
              FROM termostat
             WHERE topic = 'h-start2'
               AND incapere = 'studio'
               AND zi = 'miercuri') h_start2,
           (SELECT max(date)
              FROM termostat
             WHERE topic = 'h-stop1'
               AND incapere = 'studio'
               AND zi = 'miercuri') h_stop1,
           (SELECT max(date)
              FROM termostat
             WHERE topic = 'h-stop2'
               AND incapere = 'studio'
               AND zi = 'miercuri') h_stop2,
           (SELECT max(date)
              FROM termostat
             WHERE topic = 'set-temp'
               AND incapere = 'studio'
               AND zi = 'miercuri') set_temp,
           (SELECT max(date)
              FROM termostat
             WHERE topic = 'studio/climat/temperatura') temp) t1
```